# Embedding YouTube playlist with JSON - stopped working

Tags: json, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I had the following code that I believe uses the deprecated YouTube API v2, in order to retrieve and display a playlist. It was working for several weeks and now has stopped - is there an API v3 way to do this if that's the issue?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLCJLiJ8uSJrCpxwz4lmnz1NvvF2SzXbhk&alt=json&callback=?&max-results=50';
var videoURL= 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
$.getJSON(playListURL, function(data) {
    var list_data="";
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
        var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
        var pubdate  = item.media$group.yt$uploaded.$t;
        var fulldate = new Date(pubdate).toLocaleDateString();
        var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
        var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
        var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
        var url = videoURL + videoID;
        var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ videoID +"/mqdefault.jpg";
        list_data += '<li><a href="'+ url +'" title="'+ feedTitle +'"><img alt="'+ feedTitle+'" src="'+ thumb +'"</a><br /><a href="'+ url +'" title="'+ feedTitle +'"><strong>'+ feedTitle+'</strong></a><br />'+ fulldate +'</li>';
        console.log(item);
    });
    $(list_data).appendTo(".cont");
});
</script>
<ul class="cont" id="double">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YouTube v2 API has been deprecated and can no longer be used.  You're going to want to use the new [PlaylistItems/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint to get video information from a playlist.

To get the videos from the playlist you specified, try changing your GET request:

Request:

```
HTTP GET: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2C+id&playlistId=PLCJLiJ8uSJrCpxwz4lmnz1NvvF2SzXbhk&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/pBQT3k1NWD9D6HOvzNhT4QS1-W0\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 10,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/wu_RMwA6QYinWSMrYXyOugKDbyI\"",
   "id": "PLl3eZeHB033DOxfNMOVENodvC_4QtQ-r2bxEjeNprDxQ",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-12-10T21:16:39.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCVUx0VcNxnHx7ZjuZK5Sthw",
    "title": "Private video",
    "description": "This video is private.",
    "channelTitle": "Late Show with David Letterman",
    "playlistId": "PLCJLiJ8uSJrCpxwz4lmnz1NvvF2SzXbhk",
    "position": 0,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "4bVgilYncao"
    }
   }
  },
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/DPNyicQckvtlwgMTintYEwYsE6g\"",
   "id": "PLl3eZeHB033DOxfNMOVENoaZ-Ybk0W0zkTL1Sliq5xeA",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-12-10T21:16:58.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCVUx0VcNxnHx7ZjuZK5Sthw",
    "title": "David Letterman Announces His Retirement from the Late Show",
    "description": "David Letterman announces that he will retire from the Late Show in 2015.\n\nLive on Letterman is up for a Webby award! Let your voice be heard and vote now! http://bit.ly/1l4oktE #WebbyAwards",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/H9eYkpgeeI8/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/H9eYkpgeeI8/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/H9eYkpgeeI8/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/H9eYkpgeeI8/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/H9eYkpgeeI8/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Late Show with David Letterman",
    "playlistId": "PLCJLiJ8uSJrCpxwz4lmnz1NvvF2SzXbhk",
    "position": 1,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "H9eYkpgeeI8"
    }
   }
  },
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/aL6XWPV0PoM50wQcyclAxsvtWy4\"",
   "id": "PLl3eZeHB033DOxfNMOVENobu4IxNcwxZw1eEEoLqHjhY",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-12-10T21:17:14.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCVUx0VcNxnHx7ZjuZK5Sthw",
    "title": "Private video",
    "description": "This video is private.",
    "channelTitle": "Late Show with David Letterman",
    "playlistId": "PLCJLiJ8uSJrCpxwz4lmnz1NvvF2SzXbhk",
    "position": 2,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "ONgN2Hgz3XE"
    }
   }
  },
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/YF1JYH8bTG20vjuPLeMR-2xkxjo\"",
   "id": "PLl3eZeHB033DOxfNMOVENoQncF7sXo86YALoy5U4yqlU",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-12-10T21:17:30.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCVUx0VcNxnHx7ZjuZK5Sthw",
    "title": "David Letterman - Future Islands: \"Seasons (Waiting On You)\"",
    "description": "Making their network TV debut, Future Islands performed \"Seasons (Waiting On You)\" from their album, \"Singles.\"",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1Ee4bfu_t3c/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1Ee4bfu_t3c/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1Ee4bfu_t3c/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Late Show with David Letterman",
    "playlistId": "PLCJLiJ8uSJrCpxwz4lmnz1NvvF2SzXbhk",
    "position": 3,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "1Ee4bfu_t3c"
    }
   }
  },
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/_Ft_7ujRwQbP7-altelmVnzwQx0\"",
   "id": "PLl3eZeHB033DOxfNMOVENoYQ9Z55P4r2KhvkV5yx-okc",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-12-10T21:17:47.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCVUx0VcNxnHx7ZjuZK5Sthw",
    "title": "Private video",
    "description": "This video is private.",
    "channelTitle": "Late Show with David Letterman",
    "playlistId": "PLCJLiJ8uSJrCpxwz4lmnz1NvvF2SzXbhk",
    "position": 4,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "Bzr5VtFvSyw"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Parse the JSON as you normally would.